# Get objects of NSDate correctly into NSDictionary

Tags: objective-c, json, xcode

I have response from Web API with some custom object, one of the fields of this object contains date. I would like to convert it on the fly to NSDictionary with correct type. Currently i was able to serialize Json NSData to string values

Comment: Use `NSDateFormatter` or directly a `NSDate` if it's a timestamp. and replace it into your NSDictionary, but a custom class may be interesting.

Comment: Yes, it is timestamp. Should I use it when calling `NSJSONSerialization`?

Comment: NSJSONSerialization will get you a `NSArray` or a `NSDictionary` at top level (depending on the JSON), filled only with `NSArray`, `NSDictionary`, `NSNumber` and `NSString` objects. It's up to you after to interpret theses values. For instance, you could create custom classes that handle it, with `-initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)jsonDict`, and in it you do `_myNSDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:[jsonDict[keyToTimestamp] doubleValue];`, and then read it with `NSLog(@"date: %@", myCustomClass.myNSDate);`

Comment: Got it, Thank you.